# How do I stop my Mac OS X from going to sleep?

Tags: sleep-wake

In settings, I don't see a way to stop the PC from going to sleep.

Answer (score 3):

Go to sys pref -Energy

Slide the Computer and display sliders all the way to the right (to the never position)

[image: sleep]

If you prefer you can use the build in (by Apple) Terminal command "Caffeinate" to set specific non sleep modes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/caffeinate.8.html

Comment: Unfortunately my Mac doesn't have a computer sleep option. :(

Comment: The used the Terminal and Caffeinate.

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily stop your Mac from sleeping, you could use [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/), a widely-used, free utility available both through the App Store as well as a direct download from the developer's site.